# How to check if exists divisible combination without calculating them all?

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to write a program that tells if there is possible to insert + or - between given integers (the value of them is up to 3 digits, the amount of them is up to 4 digits) to get a number divisible by another number (int up to 2 digits). The amount of these integers (a 4 digits number) makes it impossible to calculate all combinations and check if any of them is divisible because of complexity O(2^n) (program should compute in a few seconds, not centuries).

My first idea was using some kind of tree and store in memory parts of results that will be useful to future calculations. I was also delete all numbers that is divisible themselves before starting calculations (because + or - that number not changes divisibility of a result). That significantly reduced the number of calculations but max amount of numbers that was computed in a few seconds was only 30. Do you have any ideas what mathematical rule can be useful in that problem?

Comment: Please check how to make a question [ask].

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
StackOverflow is not a coding, review, or tutorial resource.

Comment: Let's look at *your* solution -- it appears to be flawed.  As I *expect* your research on line has already shown, there are plenty of solutions for inserting operators, in all combinations, into a sequence of numbers.  Those solutions complete in a couple of heartbeats.  Follow the links we've given you, and let us help you preserve *your* solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number x is divisible by y if and only if x is equal to 0 modulo y.

Therefore all you need to track is which values modulo y are reachable.

When you have no numbers, the only value is 0.

When you add a number, you can either add or subtract the value so you may make up to 2 new values reachable.

So for each stage, simply check for each possible modulo value whether it is reachable.

The overall complexity will be O(n.y) where n is the count of numbers to be added/subtracted and y is the number that it must be divisible by.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible that I've misunderstood the aim of your algorithm, but I would have a hard time believing that any modern computer would take longer than a few seconds to this. I don't understand where you could have made an algorithm that takes centuries in the course of this problem.

The following is a basic brute-force algorithm that iterates over pairs `(i:1-1000, j:1-1000)` and computes the full list of shared divisors between `|i-j|` and `i+j`. If this does not answer your question, please try to clarify the algorithm in plain English without skipping words (i.e. "Amount of" should likely have a "The" out front).

```js
function getDivisors(n: number): number[] {
  let i: number = 2;
  let divisors: number[] = [];
  for (i; i < Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
    if (n % i == 0) {
      divisors.push(i);
    }
  }
  return divisors;
}

function existsCombination(n: number, m: number): number[] {
  let dPlus: number[] = getDivisors(n+m);
  let dMinus: number[] = getDivisors(Math.abs(n-m));
  return dPlus.filter((d: number) => dMinus.indexOf(d) !== -1);
}

for (let i: number = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  for (let j: number = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
    let common: number[] = existsCombination(i, j);
    if (common.length > 0) {
    console.log(`(i, j): (${i}, ${j}) => (${Math.abs(i-j)},${i+j})
    common divsiors: ${existsCombination(i, j)}`);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You are right, I didn't explain this clearly, I edited the question, I hope it's more clear now. In your code there are 2 numbers (i and j) and two loops. The problem is there can be up to 9999 these numbers.

Comment: Are you provided with an input list of numbers and an input divisor?

Comment: yes, and output is a boolean (divisible combination exists or not)